# Is there a sender for UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: uitableview

What would I send as the sender if a row is selected from a UITableView.  I have a method that is an IBAction that normally takes an argument of type id.

```
:(id)sender
```

I want to call this same method from a UITableView when a row is selected, but I didn't know what to pass as the sender. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass self.

```
[self someAction: self];
```

if the method can handle sender being nil, you can also pass nil indicating it was called directly.

```
[self someAction: nil];
```

Which is preferred depends on the method.